# How to follow the page directly without opening Facebook URL in angular?

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using Facebook Graph API in angular. There is a button named "Follow" in our angular site, we want to follow specific Facebook page directly on click of that button without opening Facebook URL.

Anyone have idea about it how to follow the page without opening Facebook site with angular?

Comment: I doubt if that is possible.

Comment: There is no API for that.